# Does Amazon change previewable pages of a book according to some factors?

Tags: amazon

I am reading the preview pages of a book on Amazon ([https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Programming-Interviews-Questions-Solutions/dp/1479274836/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1479274836)).

There are many clickable (i.e. with links to the main text) chapter and section titles in the table of content, but when I read a fewer number of pages, I can't access any more pages, and the chapter and section titles in the table of content become non-clickable.

E.g. Section 18.12 in the table of content was clickable before [image] but not after [image] and the majority of the books becomes not previewable [image]

1. Do different IPs have different sets of previewable pages of a book?
2. Are the previewable pages of a book different for different Amazon accounts?
3. Does Amazon change the previewable pages of a book over time? E.g., If I wait for a week, a month, or some length of time, will the previewable pages for my account change?
4. What are some other factors?